# angular.js ng-change does not work on a select changed by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using select2 to stylish a select input. These select input is multi-select enabled and is used to filter results on page, as user choose it's filters, I have to update a grid. Then, as select2 hide original select input and put a stylized div in it's place, all changes to the original select is made programmatically, for this reason, angular ngChange does not work.

--
jquery provide us thousands of plugins that help us to make awesome user friendly interactions. Maybe it all will be writen purely in angular.js but right now, we have to go fast in development and deliver it to customer. And in many times it can't wait for us rewrite old code to new technology. so, in transition from jquery to angular.js, we have to use both together for a long time yet. For this reason, we need, somtimes a flexible way to use it. and the ability to call a internal method of the angular`s controller would be a good solution

Comment: This makes sense because ng-change only works when the model is changed. Have you tried using $scope.$apply() to make sure the model changes when jQuery changes it?

Comment: well mixing angular and jquery is questionable. who knows what problems that will cook up. Really you should use a ng-select and ng-model not select2. Also the function you call to update the grid you could wrap in a $timeout so that as @AR7 said make sure $scope.$apply is being handled correctly.

Comment: Jess, te decision to use of select2 came from designers, native select is not so much customizable. you mean I have to put a $timeout to watch if select2 was changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you makes change outside the context of Angular (i.e. using jQuery), angular won't notice the changes and therefore, it won't run the $digest cycle.

You should wrap your changes in a `$scope.$apply(function(){ .. })`

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs does not accept changes made by Jquery.You should do all your stuff in Angular to make you app more accurate. Also add code what you have done so far.

Comment: jquery provide us thousands of plugins that help us to make user friendly interactions. Maybe it all will be writen purely in angular.js but right now, we have to go fast in development and deliver it to customer. And in many times it can't wait for us rewrite old code to new technology. so, in transition from jquery to angular.js, we have to use both together for a long time yet. For this reason, we need, somtimes a flexible way to use it. and the ability to call a internal method of the angular`s controller would be a good solution